# EntityFieldQuery - ordering by multiplication of two fields

Tags: 7, database, entities

I need to order my news by their importance value (1, 2 or 3) which is in the field field_importance and the date they are published. So I would need to order my news by this calculation: created * field_importance and I haven't figured out a way to do it with EntityFieldQuery. If someone knows a way to do it without EntityFieldQuery, that's equally good. This is my code so far:

```
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
      ->propertyCondition('type', array('news'))
      ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to pull in a whole bunch of linked entity stuff, just run a regular db_query() joining your "importance" field table to your node table.

`$query = "SELECT nid, (created * field_importance_value) AS weight
FROM node n 
JOIN field_data_field_importance f ON f.entity_id = n.nid
WHERE type = 'news'
AND status = 1
ORDER BY weight DESC";
$result = db_query($query);
// Add foreach loop here...`

I'm just guessing the importance table name and field name from your OP.